# Sensor can not read temperature

Tags: marlin, inductive-sensor, mks

I have MKS TinyBee board recently purchased. The temperature sensor reading gives either 'Err' or '0'.

I have tried all possible sensors in the Marlin table configuration, but still none of them worked. As well as 3 different sensors.
Is the board faulty or I'm missing a setting?

[image: Photo of temperature sensor display]

Comment: Did you try plugging the thermistor into the other thermistor ports on the board to see if it will work then?

Comment: I tried both ports, still the same

Comment: Did you find a way around this problem?

Comment: How about something simple... have you check continuity on the wire between the logic board and the sensor?

Answer (score 2):

I get this issue, more or less the same.
In my case, it wont read temperature UNLESS both X and Y steppers are active. If any of those is open, it displays err/0.

Comment: Welcome to 3D Printing! If you have a NEW question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](//3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. If you have sufficient reputation, [you may upvote](//3dprinting.stackexchange.com/privileges/vote-up) the question. Alternatively, "star" it as a favorite and you will be notified of any new answers.